# Laravel 4 Input::only wildcards

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is there a way to use wildcards in Input::only in Laravel 4?

For example:

```
$actInputs = Input::only('act*');
```

Only give me the inputs that starts with string `act`.

Comment: What do you get when using this code?

Comment: It returns null in the browser when I var_dump it

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$actInputs = array();
foreach (Input::all() as $id => $value) {
   if (preg_match('/^act(\w+)/i', $id))
      $actInputs[$id] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I thought an alternative way

### (inputStartsWith, inputEndsWith and InputMatching )

```
// inputStartsWith a string
function inputStartsWith($pattern = null)
{
    $input = Input::all(); $result = array();
    array_walk($input, function ($v, $k) use ($pattern, &$result) {
        if(starts_with($k, $pattern)) {
            $result[$k] = $v;
        }
    });
    return $result;
}
```

**Use it like :**

```
$inputs = inputStartsWith('act');
```

**Update :** (Also `inputEndsWith`)

```
// inputEndsWith a string
function inputEndsWith($pattern = null)
{
    $input = Input::all(); $result = array();
    array_walk($input, function ($v, $k) use ($pattern, &$result) {
        if(ends_with($k, $pattern)) {
            $result[$k] = $v;
        }
    });
    return $result;
}
```

**Use it like :**

```
$inputs = inputEndsWith('_name');
```

It's possible to use these as `helper` functions or `extend` the `core` class and add these functions.

**Update : (Pattern matching)**

```
function InputMatching($pattern) {
    $input = Input::all();
    return array_intersect_key(
        $input,
        array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), 0))
    );
}
```

**Use it like :**

```
// will match 'first_name1' and 'first_name2' (ends with digit)
$inputs = InputMatching("/^.*\d$/");
```

[This Could be helpful.](http://heera.it/extend-input-class-laravel-4)